# Sum of all elements in a matrix with specified conditions

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, summation

Let M be a matrix with 20 rows and 21 columns, containing the following elements

$M[i][j]=i*i$ if $i=j$

$M[i][j]=min(i,j)$ if $i≠j$

for $1\leqslant i\leqslant 20, 1\leqslant j\leqslant 21$.

What is the sum of all elements in the matrix?

**My approach:**

I drew a $4\times 5$ matrix with the specified elements and figured out that there are:

$i+j-1-1=7$ elements of $1$

$i+j-3-1=5$ elements of $2$

$i+j-5-1=3$ elements of $3$

$i+j-7-1=1$ elements of $4$

Plus the squared elements $(1,4,9,16)$

Now, for the $M[20][21]$, following the same approach ,we have:

$S=(39\times1+37\times2+\ldots+1\times20)+(1+4+\ldots+20)=S'+S"$

$S'=39\times1+37\times2+\ldots+1\times20=2870$

$S"=1+4+\ldots+20=1/6\times20\times(20+1)\times(2\times20+1)=2870$

$S=2\times2870=5740$

So, my questions are:

1. How can I calculate $S'$ without doing every operation?
2. Is there a easier way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any special formula for this strange kind of matrix, but a closed-form sum for any $m \times n$ matrix is fairly simple to figure out. I will do this for $n > m$, since that is what you have above, but you can simply switch these dimensions in the final formula if $m > n$.

You have already worked out most of the pattern. Let's take the $4 \times 7$ example which looks like

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
1 & 2 & 9 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 16 & 4 & 4 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
$$

We can quickly count that the sum for this is $80$, but let's break it down.

You have already shown that the diagonal of squares has to be treated separately and has a known formula

$$
\sum_{i=1}^m i^2 = \frac{m(m+1)(2m+1)}{6}
$$

We can see that everything above the diagonal follows an obvious pattern and everything below is simply reflected, but truncated because of the smaller dimension.

For the elements above the diagonal it is simply the sum from $1$ to $m$ of the row number $i$, repeated $n - i$ times, which is

$$
\sum_{i=1}^m i (n - i)
$$

For the elements below the diagonal it is similar, but note that the sum is again up to $m$, not $n$, due to the truncation

$$
\sum_{i=1}^m i (m - i)
$$

Bringing this all together, the total sum can be given as

\begin{align}
S & = \sum_{i=1}^m i^2 + \sum_{i=1}^m i (n - i) + \sum_{i=1}^m i (m - i) \\\\
& = \sum_{i=1}^m [i^2 + i (n - i) + i (m - i)] \\\\
& = \sum_{i=1}^m [i^2 + i n - i^2 + i m - i^2] \\\\
& = \sum_{i=1}^m [(m + n) i - i^2] \\\\
& = (m + n) \sum_{i=1}^m i - \sum_{i=1}^m i^2 \\\\
& = (m + n) \frac{m(m+1)}{2} - \frac{m(m+1)(2m+1)}{6} \\\\
& = \frac{m(m+1)(3m + 3n) - m(m+1)(2m+1)}{6} \\\\
& = \frac{m(m+1)(m + 3n - 1)}{6}
\end{align}

For $4 \times 7$ this is indeed $80$ and for your big $20 \times 21$ example it is, as you calculated, $5740$.

As I indicated at the start, you can swap $m$ and $n$ if the matrix is taller than it is wide, and it will still work. Alternatively, if you always know that $n = m + 1$ you can obviously further simplify this final formula.